# Change distribution of fields in a categorical variable by given distribution

Tags: r

Let's say we have a data.frame such as the one below:

```
City
NYC
Boston
NYC
NYC
Providence 
Boston
NYC
```

I want to write the simplest possible function

```
redistribute <- function(data, column, unique_value, decrease_by) {
  #data = dataframe provided by user
  #column = column of the respective dataframe
  #unique_value = fields contained within the respective column of the respective dataframe
  #decrease_by = the desired "portion" or "distribution" of the unique_value within column. 
}
```

Edit:

I will rephrase the question, as it seems to be slightly confusing.

1. I need to calculate the frequency of the (argument unique_value) within the column. *For example, that would be 4/7 or 0.57 for NYC in the City column.*
2. Decrease the number of occurrences of the unique_value so that the frequency reaches the one provided by the user in the function argument. *For example, from a 0.57 to (argument decreased_by) for NYC. So.. from 0.57 to 0.10 for instance.*
3. Replace the original fields originally occupied by the unique_value with the different values in the column. Do this randomly. *For example, we remove the first occurrence of 'NYC' field to reduce the overall frequency of the unique value 'NYC' from 0.5 to 0.1, and replace it with some random city 'Boston' for example.*

So the expected outcome would be:

```
City
NYC 
Boston
Boston
Providence
Boston
Providence
Boston
```

I'd like to avoid doing a dozen transformations. I'm looking for the most logical/efficient approach.

Comment: This makes little sense. There is no definition in your question of "redistribute" or specification of any particular "percent". To "redistribute" something you would need to put each part of it "somewhere". If this is a translation difficulty for  a different language to English, then make another attempt. Perhaps you want the `sample` function?  but it's hard to tell as the question currently reads. (AND do not use comments to amend your question. USE [edit] facilities.)

Comment: @42- I rephrased the question. Hopefully, it makes sense now.

Comment: Can you explain why 2 out of 5 entries would be "frequency" (a better word would be proportion) of 0.1? Also now need to explain why the lengths of the two vectors would be different.

Comment: @42- frequency typically refers to the number of times a particular value repeats within a vector in database terminology as far as I recall. but yes, in a nutshell, i want to alter the proportion of the unique values within a column.

Comment: @42-not sure what you mean by two vectors. theres a single vector (one column dataframe).

Comment: The first instance had 7 entries, the second had 5 (and one of those five was "BostonProvidence" Why?

Comment: @42- it was just a typo. i changed the OP for clarity. the expected vector/df is of the exact same length. just different distribution/proportion of the unique values within the column.

Answer (score 0):

What your I think your trying to do is really just putting together a few things into a function. Using your example, lets assume `new_level` is the percentage of that factor that you want in the new data.

```
city = c("NYC", "Boston", "NYC", "NYC", "Providence", "Boston", "NYC")
data = data.frame(city=city)

redistribute <- function(data, column, unique_value, new_level){
        ## Names of factors and size of data
        fac_names <- levels(factor(data[,column]))
        size <- nrow(data)

        ## Make new list using rep and sample with desired ratio
        new_col <- c(rep(unique_value,
                        floor(new_level*size)),
                        sample(fac_names[which(fac_names!=unique_value)],
                               size=(size-floor(new_level*size)),
                               replace=TRUE))

        ## Mix up and assign to data frame
        data[,column] <- sample(new_col)
        return(data)
}

redistribute(data, column="city",
                unique_value="NYC",
                new_level=0.3)
```